# How to block certain files from opening/previewing in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im working on a large front end project in vscode. Whenever I have to discard/delete/move/... the output build.js files, it tries opening these files in the editor which takes ages to load and freezes vscode (more than 5k lines each).

The only work-around I currently have to delete these files, is to `cd` to their directory and run `rm -rf ./*`. But even then, I'm looking for a more convenient way of deleting these files without vscode trying to open them.

So my question: Is there a way, by editing the settings maybe, of telling vscode to ignore and never preview files that are of a certain type or filename like `"*build.js"` (I have multiple of these big files called `a.build.js`, `b.build.js`, ...

*running git bash terminal on windows 10, vscode verson: 1.25.1*

**Edit**

1. adding the following to User Settings

   ```
   "files.exclude": {
       ...,
       "**/*.build.js": true
   },
   ```

   Will not really help as it will not hide the files from my git changes. Right-clicking the files to discard, will still take *ages* to
   complete.
   [image]
2. Adding `/public/dist*` to `.gitignore` will also not work as
   sometimes these files need to be pushed to the server, and sometimes
   they just need to be discarded.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to preview/open files only with double-click instead of single-click: `"workbench.list.openMode": "doubleClick"`.

Comment: Aside from what you're really asking, it's a common practice to exclude the "build-related" files even from source control (e.g. git) - and vscode picks this up automatically and ignores these files as well.

Comment: I know it's bad practice but our current deployment strategy is so shit, that I have to commit and push the buildfiles to our server in order for it to work, building on the server is nearly impossible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because the vscode doesn't support this**, for the "discard changes" scenario, you can use e.g. npm script, a gulp task, etc. and run it via vscode.

**Example - npm script:**

```
"scripts": {
    "discard-build-files": "git checkout -- ./src/config/env/*.js"
}
```

**Enable NPM Script Explorer:**
In vscode preferences, set up this option
`"npm.enableScriptExplorer": true`

You should then get a new section inside your Explorer view.

[image]

Comment: Knowing now that this is not supported by vscode I accept this answer as a valid and convenient work-around, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**Vscode currently doesn't support pattern filtering for previews.**

The best I can think of:

1. Exclude your desired pattern altogether from the file explorer
2. Disable the single-click preview, and make it a more explicit action
   via double-click

---

Ad 1.

Go to vscode's preferences and search for `files.exclude`.
Then edit the patterns to your liking.

[image]

Ad 2.

Go to vscode's preferences and search for `workbench.list.openMode`.
Then change the value from singleClick to doubleClick.

[image]

Comment: I updated my question. Changing `openMode` will change my entire way of working, it's a big change for just fixing a small issue.